# Struggling with this problem structure defined array as a function parameter

Tags: visual-c++

So I have this lab question that calls for creating a structure called Triangle, with the following attributes: base (double), height (double), and area (double). Then creating a function called computeArea() that has a single Triangle structure as a parameter and returns the triangle’s area. Next, the main function must create an array to hold 5 instances of Triangle and use a for loop to have the user input the base and height dimensions for each instance and call computeArea() to calculate then store its area in the struct’s attribute. My confusion lies where I need to input the function call. I can't seem to find any for the Triangle parameter to work. I've tried passerby functions, adding an "*" and changing around the variables types of the functions void so that they wouldn't interfere too much with the rest of the program.

Here is my code my current. How do I go about fixing it?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Triangle {
    double base, height, area;
};

    struct Triangle arr[5];

void computeArea(Triangle *arr[]);

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cin >> arr[i].base;
        cin>>arr[i].height;
        arr[i].height =(arr[i].base * arr[i].height/2.0);
        computeArea(arr[i]);
}

void computeArea(Triangle& arr[]); {

}
```

Comment: Consider moving the computeArea() call out of the for-loop.  So you actually have an initialized array available and can simply pass `arr`.  Or change its parameter type to Triangle so it works on a single triangle object.

Comment: You say `computeArea` should take a single `Triangle` as a parameter. But neither of the two different declarations have it take a single `Triangle`. `void computeArea(Triangle *arr[])` takes an array of pointers to `Triangle`; `void computeArea(Triangle& arr[])` is syntactically ill-formed and won't compile at all. In general, one doesn't arrive at correct working code by randomly adding punctuation in hopes of stumbling on the right incantation; consider consulting your favorite C++ textbook.